# How to escape do something in if/else block in c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<%  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{ 
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PictureName10)){
%>
        <img src="picturename10.png" />
<%   }else{


     }
}
%>
```

I don't know how can I continue to do next loop(i=1) when go in to block else{ ..}.

Comment: add a continue statement in else block

Comment: looks like your code does exactly that... what's wrong with it ? you might aswell remove the else block since it's empty.

Comment: It break my layout if I used continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably don't need an `else` statement

Comment: It work well with my layout if I do that, but at my 10th block, it show the empty things.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean, but I think you need a `continue;` statement.